# Why are latent spaces able to learn representations - autoencoder?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, neural-networks

As the title states, why are latent spaces even able to intelligently learn representations? There's no guarantee that we learn the most important features since it's all done automatically in something like an autoencoder. In comparison, with other dimensionality reduction algorithms, e.g., PCA, have ways of logically choosing what dimensions to keep.

Is there some proof for why latent spaces are able to learn intelligent representations?

Comment: I am not sure that you are in the correct forum. Maybe cross validated could be a better fit.

Comment: No one has given me an answer there, so I thought I'd ask here since there is some overlap between the two communities. Cross-validated has less of a focus on proof in my experience.

Comment: I understand. I am not sure that there are 'proofs'. Personally I just know the intuitive reasoning that autoencoders perform 'data compression' and to compress something you need to distill information. But I am curious to know something more mathematical about it. Maybe looking back at the probablistic derivation of variational autoencoders one has more intuition...

Comment: Not exactly in my strike zone, but in the intersection with what I have studied: [pro](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2010/file/a49e9411d64ff53eccfdd09ad10a15b3-Paper.pdf), [mid](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.02633), and [con](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=B1tExikAW).  These papers (chosen semi-randomly from the torrent) suggest simility with other unsupervised learning techniques, so the real answer to your question may not be clear-cut presently (something like an "unsupervised learning thesis", a parallel to the Turing thesis about universality of computation models).